# rc control user

Tags: users, init-script, openbsd

I am playing around with rc scripts. I am starting a daemon from rc.local. I would like to know how I start the process under a specific user instead of root?

Answer (score 5):

What daemon? Most daemons come with a commandline or config option to drop privileges. But if you're looking for a generic way, try:

```
RUN_AS=my_user
su -c /usr/sbin/my_daemon $RUN_AS
```

Comment: Why bother putting RUN_AS into a variable here?

Comment: Post that in a new question, and I'll elaborate on what advantages and possibilities it will bring.